# CS0411 The type arguments inferred from the usage

Tags: c#, generic-list

I know lots of people ask about CS0411 error, but almost every one of them is about defining the metods (at least the ones i checked). But mine is different; i have three methods, they all have same return types (List), but they distinct from eachother by their parameters. And when i'm trying to use them, one of them works but other two give error. they are same except for the parameters, which distinguishes them from eachother.. is there something i am missing?

```
    public static List<T> Occupy<T>(int count, T fillWith)
    {
        if (count < 0)
            count = 0;
        return Occupy<T>(count, false, fillWith);
    }
    public static List<T> Occupy<T>(bool clear)
    {
        return Occupy<T>(-1, clear, null);
    }
    public static List<T> Occupy<T>()
    {
        return Occupy<T>(-1, true, null);
    }
```

these three being compiled successfuly, i am getting error when i try to call them:

```
    List<bool> pointHits = LstN.Occupy(contTotal, false);  //no error

    List<bool> pointPrevHandles = LstN.Occupy(true);  //CS0411 error

    List<bool> parallels = LstN.Occupy(contTotal, false);  //no error

    List<bool> pointNextHandles = LstN.Occupy();  //CS0411 error
```

any idea?

Comment: The only place the compiler could infer `T` in the failing examples is from the destination variable. See marked duplicate for why C# infers types only from the _inputs_ of a method call, not the outputs.

Comment: ohh i see the "fillWith" parameter helps the compiler undertands the item type of the list... sory for repeting this question.. thanks